# Ubuntu: Method of periodically launching python scripts other than/with Crontab?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I've been running an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu as a means of periodically running my recurring python scripts. My scripts are mostly simple, using the requests module to make 1-5 requests per script. I've built up a library of about 10 scripts at this point.

So to run these scripts, I currently use Crontab to run each of these scripts each minute. So crontab looks like this:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# H D M Wd Command
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
* * * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/script1/script1.py
* * * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/script2/script2.py
* * * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/script3/script3.py
...
```

This has worked fine for a while, but I think I've built up enough scripts that it seems to be causing a problem. When I ssh into the instance, the load is often higher than 1.0. After a while, my instance will either crash or become so slow as to have functionally crashed.

I think the source of the problem may have something to do with the fact crontab start all scripts programmed this way at the same time at the start of every minute. If the scripts were more spread out over the minute it would probably go over smoother. However, crontab doesn't allow me to have control over launches at a rate below 1 per minute.

it would probably go over smoother. However, crontab doesn't allow me to have control over launches at a rate below 1 per minute.
Is there an alternative method of launching these scripts instead of/in addition to Crontab? Preferably a method where, if one of my scripts fails for some reason, does not derail all my scripts?

Comment: If you're going to run them that frequently and they're all python scripts, why not just use [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)? Also, are you sure those scripts are terminating before they're next run?

Comment: @Ouroborus Can you elaborate on what you mean about python scripts? What exactly are you suggesting? I think that the scripts are terminating but I'm not certain.

Comment: You might have a infinite loop, a race condition, the script might take more than a minute to complete, etc...

Comment: Now, that I think about it, if you have 10 scripts making 5 requests every minutes that's 72 000 requests a day. I don't know what these scripts are for but I would expect some servers to refuse or delay your connection. Does your script account for failed/delayed connections? Do you really need this to be every minute?

Comment: @SyKer most of them only make one request. The most is about 5. I actually don't really get connections refused at a rate of 1 per minute. I also use request scripts that have failure conditions. And worse case should be one instance of the script throws an exception for an execution, which should just quickly end. So I don't think that particular part is the problem

Comment: It's hard to say without a good look at the script/server but `crontab` shouldn't be problematic. I would first run `ps -ax` or something similar to see if one or more process is stuck. Then have a look at the memory usage with `htop`. And then I would troubleshoot the scripts themselves: create a log file with timestamps, what's happening at what time etc... But the only time this has happened to me was because of a zombie concurrent process.

Comment: @SyKer ok thank you that's very helpful/ So when trying to find stuck processes, do you just use ps -ax and look for which processes have lasted the longest based on the time it spits out? And maybe just spam ps -ax until you see a runaway process?

Answer (score 1):

As I see it you have several choices.

**Chain the scripts:**

```
* * * * * python3 /home/ubuntu/script1/script1.py; python3 /home/ubuntu/script2/script2.py; python3 /home/ubuntu/script3/script3.py; ...
```

This ensures no script runs at the same time. Unless they pass the 1 minute mark and starts again and nothing is done to prevent it.

**Add a milisecond sleep:**

```
* * * * * sleep 0.1; python3 /home/ubuntu/script1/script1.py
* * * * * sleep 0.2; python3 /home/ubuntu/script1/script2.py
```

This again doesn't prevent them from running at the same time. Only delays them.

The better solution would probably be to write a python service which runs continously and have proper control over when the scripts are run.
It could be as simple as a `while True` loop over all your scripts. Maybe add a sleep between runs.